# Override SCP (Simple Configurable Products) Block

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, module

Hi I try to override getAllowProducts() method from Mage/Core/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php with local module to show Out of stock products in configurable attribute dropdown.

I use Magento CE 1.9 and Simple Configurable Products (SCP) extension. Product_View_Type_Configurable class is already overriden by SCP so I rewrite SCP class using depends.

When I activate my module, configurable attribute dropdown and product data desappear from template catalog/product/view.phtml.

Is anybody help for this issue ?

Here is the code of my module :

**etc/modules** : app/etc/modules/Mycompany_SimpleConfigurableProducts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_SimpleConfigurableProducts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
                    <depends>
                        <Mage_Catalog />
                        <OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts />
                    </depends>
        </Mycompany_SimpleConfigurableProducts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**config.xml** in app/code/local/Mycompany/SimpleConfigurableProducts/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_SimpleConfigurableProducts>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mycompany_SimpleConfigurableProducts>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_type_configurable>Mycompany_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Configurable.php** in /app/code/local/Mycompany/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type

```
<?php
class Mycompany_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable extends OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable{

    public function getAllowProducts()
    {
        if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
            $products = array();
            $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
            $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getUsedProducts(null, $this->getProduct());
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                // Get Out of stock simple products
                //if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck) {
                    $products[] = $product;
                //}
            }
            $this->setAllowProducts($products);
        }
        return $this->getData('allow_products');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake, I have a wrong path for Configurable.php

I replace

```
/app/code/local/Mycompany/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type
```

by

```
/app/code/local/Mycompany/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type
```

and it works :)