# Simple product belonging to a configurable product not showing its details when clicking its thumbnail

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, simple-product

I have a simple product which belongs to a configurable product. The simple product is out of stock. But in the front-end it is showing is corresponding thumbnail. And on clicking that thumbnail, it is showing the details of next available simple product.

I want to show the correct details of that simple product. When I made the simple product it stock and quantity to 10, it is showing correctly. But without changing that I want to display the details of product. Even though I cannot add it to the cart.

I am using Magento **1.7.0.2**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "n the front-end it is showing is corresponding thumbnail". Color swatches is not available in magento 1.7. Are you using a third party extension for that? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: @Marius Please see the screenshot

Comment: I still don't understand. What is the thumbnail that you are talking about? By default, for a configurable product, magento show the thumbnails of the configurable product itself, not of it's child simple products. And clicking on a thumbnail does not open the simple product details. It just opens the big image corresponding to the thumbnail you clicked.

Comment: I am showing the thumbnails of child simple products. On clicking the thumbnail, it shows the big image and details of the simple product

Comment: Can you provide a link? I think it will help us understand better

Comment: You'll most likely want Simple Configurable Products (SCP) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46143/override-scp-simple-configurable-products-block